# Triggering scheduler for actuator/refresh

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring cloud config projects for reading properties from Git.at run time if i am changing anything i need to build and run the application.so i used http://localhost:8085/pat-tbx-dlr-product/management/refresh to update values to be reflected at run time .so i used feign client and scheduler to run in every 5 sec so i dont have to refresh manually to get updated values from git.

```
@Validated
@FeignClient(name = "tbx-schedulerservice", url = "http://localhost:8085/pat-tbx-dlr-product/management")
public interface SchedulerFeignService {
    @PostMapping(value = "/refresh", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public TBXResponseWrapperVoid refreshActuator(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> header);

}



@Component
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="cloud-config.auto-refresh.enabled", havingValue="true")
@EnableAsync
public class ConfigAutoRefresh {
    
    @Autowired
    SchedulerFeignService schedulerFeignService;
    
    //@Scheduled(fixedRateString="${cloud-config.auto-refresh.rate-in-ms:5000}")
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
      public void refresh() {
        
        schedulerFeignService.refreshActuator(new HashMap<String, String>());
          
      }

}
```

The problem is still i dont get refreshed value